# Is an age gate required on sites for M- or AO-rated games?

Tags: esrb

As given in the title, is an age gate required on sites for M- or AO-rated games?  I am not sure, but it appears that the ESRB requires it.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ESRB requires all ESRB Website Council (EWC) members to add age gates to all websites for Mature-rated or Adults Only-rated games:

> 2.2 If the audio-visual content contains material from a Mature-rated or Adults Only-rated game (or one that is anticipated to receive either rating), display an ESRB-compliant age-gate prior to access or purchase.
>
> 2.3 Utilize an age-neutral approach (e.g., “Please enter your date of birth.”), when requesting the manual entry of a birth date from a visitor trying to access age-gated audio-visual content;
>
> 2.4 Employ reasonable measures (e.g., dropping a session cookie; returning visitor to the home page) to prevent visitors under the age of 17 (or 18) from re-entering a different birth date once they have initially been denied access to age-gated audio-visual content and utilize an age-neutral approach in the error message (e.g., “Sorry, you may not access this content.”);

Source: [ESRB Website Council "Code of Conduct"](https://esrbstorage.blob.core.windows.net/esrbcontent/ratings/downloads/ewc_code.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: of course since there is no way for the site to verify the age entered into the gate the whole thing seems rather moot.

Comment: It's weird how a majority of gamers were born on January 1st.